# Image doesn't show in IE8

Tags: html, https, internet-explorer-8, image

I have a `<img>` that has url to show my image like:

```
<img src="https://stage.connect2fans.com/download.svc/ec9f28cf-0e11-467f-b2d7-8d7728e775ce/ticket/GeneralAdmissionTicketInventoryItem/67cf47e6-932d-40da-aacc-c10b9f78ea36" />
```

It is showed on FF, Chrome But it doesn't show on IE8. How to do that? Thanks so much.

Comment: That image url doesn't work for me at all. "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details." It loads something in FF?

Comment: Yes, It have to login to see the image. When I logged in, I can see image with the url on the browser. But <img> tag doesn't show it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it possible that your IE8 security settings are getting in the way? Any chance you can create us a temporary login so we can investigate? You might want to check the HTTP response of the image in your browser to see if there's an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I know the problem is the cookie is blocked for my site so I need to turn on in IE8 to solve:

```
Go into Tools > Internet Options > Sites to turn on cookie for my site
```